# Extracting data out of nested Json in c#

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-phone-7

I want to develop a weather application for windows phone.I have created a simple UI for testing purpose.Containing a one grid with textbox and button to enter city name.Second grid have different labels to show weather data after button is tapped.

I am using api from **openweathermap.org**.I have made classes out of Json data:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-120.5,"lat":47.5},"sys":{"message":0.195,"country":"US","sunrise":1384787560,"sunset":1384820527},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"sky is clear","icon":"01d"}],"base":"gdps stations","main":{"temp":277.15,"pressure":1010,"humidity":86,"temp_min":277.15,"temp_max":277.15},"wind":{"speed":0.31,"deg":230.5},"rain":{"3h":1},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1384797300,"id":5815135,"name":"Washington","cod":200}
```

And The classes are:

```
    public class Coord
{
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public double message { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public int sunrise { get; set; }
    public int sunset { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
    public double pressure { get; set; }
    public double sea_level { get; set; }
    public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public string  { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int cod { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Json.net to extract data out of obtained json.My Json data do not have a list but a single object.I have seen examples how a list can be bound to ListItem in xaml.But I do not know how to do that on single object.
XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="boxOfSearch" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Name="getEnteredString" Margin="2,1"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" x:Name="btnGet" Tap="btnGet_Tap">Go</Button>
            <!--<Button x:Name="goButton" Content="Go" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,1"                         Click="goButton_Click"/>-->
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="extractedData" Height="532">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="getName" Text="{Binding name}"  Margin="2,2,2,5" Foreground="#FF176EB5" FontSize="48" TextAlignment="Center" />
```

What I want to have as output are:Name of city,high and low temperature.Name and Temperature are from different classes.If I can get these values separately it can be a great starting point for me.

```
    private void btnGet_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(""));
        wc.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_DownloadStringCompleted);
    }

    void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);                        

        var rootObj=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);  //Getting DeserializedObject in a variable
        getJsonStrTxtBox.Text = rootObj.name;       // var.name  where name (Name of the City) is a string in RootObject class
    }                                                //like var.name add var.main.temp_max
```

Now I am able to get any data from nested json. Json.net and @evanmcdonnal thank you very much.

[image: City name plus temprature]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm slightly confused by your question but it sounds like you're really just looking for something like this;

```
    RootObject response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseBody);

    string message = String.Format("City: {0} - high: {1}, low: {2}", response.name, response.main.temp_max, response.main.temp_mix);

     MessageBox.Show(message);
```

NOTE: I would recommend some checks for nullity which I have not included in the above example (is response null? Ok, is response.main null?). When you use json.NET's `DeserializeObject` method on a complex object the deserialization is "cascading" (for lack of better term) meaning all of the objects which the class you're deserializing is composed of will also be deserialized appropriately. From there you would access them like with any other object, there is just another layer of indirection.

Comment: I was able to get Name of the city with.Using object.name or your mentioned response.name already.But Maximum and Minimum Temrature are in different class named "Main" and Path is RootObject-->Main.

Comment: @NavS sorry I didn't read your class definitions closely enough, update coming.

Comment: Thank you very much.It worked.Sometimes you can not get even simplest things if someone is not there to guide you.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://james.newtonking.com/json

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var json =
                "{\"coord\":{\"lon\":-120.5,\"lat\":47.5},\"sys\":{\"message\":0.195,\"country\":\"US\",\"sunrise\":1384787560,\"sunset\":1384820527},\"weather\":[{\"id\":800,\"main\":\"Clear\",\"description\":\"sky is clear\",\"icon\":\"01d\"}],\"base\":\"gdps stations\",\"main\":{\"temp\":277.15,\"pressure\":1010,\"humidity\":86,\"temp_min\":277.15,\"temp_max\":277.15},\"wind\":{\"speed\":0.31,\"deg\":230.5},\"rain\":{\"3h\":1},\"clouds\":{\"all\":1},\"dt\":1384797300,\"id\":5815135,\"name\":\"Washington\",\"cod\":200}";

            dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

            Console.WriteLine(obj.coord.lon + "  " + obj.coord.lat);

            Console.ReadLine(); 
        }
    }
```

Extract the data first and map it to the classes. And then handle the UI events.